# How to save application's preferences on server and load them

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-settings

I need to load preferences from server and changes must be stored on same server. what I understood from [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) link is that if I use PreferenceActivity class it stores the preferences automatically in SharedPreferences.

What I need, to fetch configurations from network and display them to user. If user changes anything then I send those changes back to server where they get stored.
My question is whether I can use PreferenceScreen and it component or should I design my own controls and GUI. Thanks

Comment: what is a need of saving setting if you are always fetching and pushing them to/from server.....just use RESTful web service...

Comment: The app is for embedded system which provides Http interface for Configurations. If user wants to change some configurations which approach is best to design GUI for this purpose. I am new to android development, please ignore my naiveness.

Comment: so what is problem in that?

Comment: Setting Activity in android Studio is great. But I doubt that I can set and retrieve individual control settings and use them.

Comment: then create you own....